# Node.js and mysql. Insert into local database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am currently working on a html form that allows the user to input their title, firstname, surname, mobile and email. Currently this data is being pushed into an in-memory database called userDatabase[].

I want to be able to insert the data into my local mysql database instead. I can connect to my database using this code with no issues.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "user",
password: "password",
database: "user",
});

con.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Connected!");
});
```

In the below code you can see that the data is getting pushed into the in-memory database.

```
        if (currentMethod === "POST") {

            // read the body of the POST request
            request.on("data", function(chunk) {
                requestBody += chunk.toString();
            });

            // determine the POST request Content-type (and log to console)
            // Either: (i)  application/x-www-form-urlencoded or (ii) application/json
            const { headers } = request;
            let ctype = headers["content-type"];
            console.log("RECEIVED Content-Type: " + ctype + "\n");

            // finished reading the body of the request
            request.on("end", function() {
                var userData = "";
                // saving the user from the body to the database
                if (ctype.match(new RegExp('^application/x-www-form-urlencoded'))) {
                    userData = querystring.parse(requestBody);
                } else {
                    userData = JSON.parse(requestBody);
                }
                //**************** */
                userDatabase.push(userData)
```

I have tried to INSERT the data into my table called "personal" like this: But I am getting an error Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`title` = 'ms', `firstname` = 'Tina', `surname` = 'poole', `mobile` = '+3...' at line 1

```
  con.query("INSERT INTO personal (title , firstname, surname, mobile , email ) VALUES ?", [userData], function(err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("1 record inserted");
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're conflating two distinct syntax patterns for MySQL's `INSERT`. In these types of situations you should be referring to the [relevant documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html).

When specifying `key='value'` pairs, the syntax for an `INSERT` would conform to the following format:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    SET assignment_list
    [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE assignment_list]
```

This format is clearly delineated from the traditional `INSERT INTO tbl_name (fieldnames) VALUES (values)` as it doesn't require either the field names nor the `VALUES` keyword, as you've included in your query syntax above. Instead, you'd include the `SET <assignment_list>` sequence, which operates similarly in syntax to a traditional `UPDATE` query.

Instead, your code would look similar to the following:

```
con.query("INSERT INTO personal SET ?", [userData], function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
});
```